# FFMPEG || Converting CCTV raw .264 footage files

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-encoding

[image of the log below is the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzBMW.png)
Hi I want to convert 264 footage files to .mp4.
The problem is these files came with a player but unfortunately that player is not working on my pc, hence I thought of converting files to mp4 so I can play them in vlc. I tried using ffmpeg but it gives following error when I use ffprobe

```
ffprobe version N-80066-g566be4f Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --e
nable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-li
bass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-li
bgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmfx --enable-libmp3l
ame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-li
bopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enab
le-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrw
benc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx
264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --en
able-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 24.100 / 55. 24.100
  libavcodec     57. 43.100 / 57. 43.100
  libavformat    57. 37.100 / 57. 37.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 46.100 /  6. 46.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[h264 @ 000000000059a660] Format h264 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection poss
ible!
[h264 @ 000000000068bf00] missing picture in access unit with size 1073672
[h264 @ 000000000068bf00] No start code is found.
[h264 @ 000000000068bf00] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 000000000059a660] decoding for stream 0 failed
[h264 @ 000000000059a660] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, none)
: unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, h264, from 'test264.264':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, none, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn
```

Any help/guidance will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you upload a sample file?

Comment: Yeah, sure. Any idea how to upload it though?

Answer (score 0):

> `Format h264 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!`

As said in this warning, FFmpeg is ambiguous on the video-format. It is quite possible to misdetect as all you have is just a syncword to guess with.

Are you sure that it is *H.264*, verify that first, it seems it isn't.